# Minimizer of two matrix energies

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, non-convex-optimization

I am looking for a solution $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which minimizes the following energy:

$$
\textrm{min}_X  \| X A X^T - B\|^2 + \mu \|X \Lambda X^T - \Lambda \|^2
$$

where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are P.D., $\Lambda$ is diagonal with positive entries, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, and $ \| \cdot \|$ is the Frobenius norm. I am hoping to find an analytical solution for $X$.

The best I've been able to come up with so far is that the system can be re-written as
$$
\textrm{min}_{Y} \| Y \textrm{vec}(A) - \textrm{vec}(B) \|^2 + \mu \| Y\textrm{vec}(\Lambda) - \textrm{vec}(\Lambda) \|^2, \qquad Y = (X  \otimes X), \, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$
from which I could solve for some matrix $Y$ but am not sure how to enforce $Y = (X \otimes X)$. This also implies that $\textrm{vec}(\Lambda)$ should be close to an eigenvector of $(X \otimes X)$ with eigenvalue $1$.

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: You would need to specify what norm, also it is not quadratic.

Comment: Setting $\mu=0$ leaves a Riccati equation with solution
$$\large{
X = A^{-1/2} (A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2} A^{-1/2} \;\equiv\; X^T
}$$
Similarly, letting  $\mu\to\infty$ yields another Riccati equation
$$\large{
\def\L{\Lambda}
X = \L^{-1/2} (\L^{1/2}\L\L^{1/2})^{1/2} \L^{-1/2} \;\equiv\; I
}$$

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, there was a typo in the original question. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: Surely it is a quartic, not a quadratic?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, thank you. Clearly, I was a little confused.